# How Do I Change My Main "environment" Location in the AWS Cloud9 Editor?

Tags: apache, aws-cloud9

I'm using AWS Cloud9 to learn how to develop a web server, but the main file menu is stuck in the `~/environment/` directory.  I am trying to use an Apache HTTP Server for this "project". Is there a way I can change the main directory it shows on the left to the apache install location, `/var/www/html/`?

The area I'm talking about is the area highlighted in yellow in the picture below.

[image: Screenshot]

Another issue with this is that I can't open the file at `/var/www/html/` in the Ace editor either. I'm assuming this is because it is in a root directory.

I'd even take a solution on how to change the website's directory from `/var/www/html/` to `/home/ec2-user/environment/` as nothing I've found via google has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change the root directory of your Apache server.

This guide explains [how to set the root directory](https://www.lucidar.me/en/aws-cloud9/how-to-run-apache-on-aws-ec2-cloud9-server/#set-apache-root-directory)

This page explains [how to configure and run Apache on AWS Cloud9](https://www.lucidar.me/en/aws-cloud9/how-to-run-apache-on-aws-ec2-cloud9-server/)